# From rastermap package to ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

My problem: I want to draw a map obtained via `rastermap` package with `ggplot2`.

Searching for alternatives to `ggmap` package I found the `rastermap` package which provides an easy way to obtain maps from external sources. The [readme](https://github.com/hadley/rastermap) provides a very simple example:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("hadley/rastermap")

houston <- fetch_region(c(-95.80204, -94.92313), c(29.38048, 30.14344),
  stamen("terrain"))
houston
plot(houston)
```

The problem comes whether I try to plot using ggplot. So far I've tried several ways but none of them seems to work. Is it possible? Any idea?

Comment: Care to share the code you've written to try and use ggplot2? It'd be helpful to have some context as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: So far I have tried using `map_data()` function from `ggplot2` package, also tried with `raster` package. All errors are about the class of the object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rastermap` generates a matrix of colours in hexadecimal strings (`#RRGGBB` format). It may be simplest to convert this to a more common form for spatial data, a multiband raster brick, with separate layers for the red, green and blue.

We can write a short helper function to convert hexadecimal strings into the separate integer values (i.e. this is the reverse of the `rgb()` function):

```
un_rgb = function (x) {
  x = unlist(str_split(x, ''))
  r = paste0(x[2], x[3])
  g = paste0(x[4], x[5])
  b = paste0(x[6], x[7])
  strtoi(c(r,g,b), 16)
}
```

Using this function we convert the rastermap matrix into a three band raster brick:

```
library(raster)    
m = as.matrix(houston)
l=lapply(m[], un_rgb)
r=g=b=matrix(, dim(m)[1], dim(m)[2])
r[] = sapply(l, function(i) i[1])
g[] = sapply(l, function(i) i[2])
b[] = sapply(l, function(i) i[3])
rgb.brick = brick(raster(r), raster(g), raster(b))
```

And set the extent of the new raster to that of the original rastermap

```
extent(rgb.brick) = extent(matrix(unlist(attributes(houston)$bb), nrow=2))
```

Now that we have a more usual form of raster object, we can do various things with it.  For example, we can plot it in ggplot using `library(RStoolbox)`:

```
ggRGB(rgb.brick, r=1, g=2, b=3)
```

[image]

Or we can save it as an image to use as an annotation background in ggplot:

```
png('test.png', dim(rgb.brick)[2], dim(rgb.brick)[1])
  plotRGB(rgb.brick, 1, 2, 3)
dev.off()

img <- png::readPNG("test.png")
gr <- grid::rasterGrob(img, interpolate=TRUE)
ggplot() + annotation_custom(gr, -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want an alternative? You can get a stamen map from [ggmap](/questions/tagged/ggmap):

```
library(ggmap)
ggmap(get_stamenmap(c(-95.80204, 29.38048, -94.92313, 30.14344))) +
# some points to plot
geom_point(aes(x = seq(-95.5, -95.2, 0.1), y = seq(29.7, 30, 0.1)), color = "red")
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Term of service... and the cap of google maps API ^^

Comment: Please check again. Above method does not use the Google Maps API.

Comment: Just for learning to use `rastermap` package. And your solution throw this error: `Map from URL : http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/10/239/422.jpg
Error in readJPEG(tmp) : 
  JPEG decompression error: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x89 0x50`